# Почему такие разные результаты?

Tags: golang

Решил написать утилиту `tree` в учебных целях.

В принципе, все работает, но почему то результаты разнятся с оригинальной утилитой `tree`, если делаю дерево для всего корневого раздела или еще какое то большое количество вложенных папок и файлов.

Подскажите, куда копать, чтобы результаты были одинаковые?

Если нужно протестировать то можете сделать

```sh
git clone https://github.com/udonetsm/mytree && cd mytree && sudo mv mytree /bin/ && cd && mytree -h
```

Код:

```go
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
    "strings"

    ct "github.com/daviddengcn/go-colortext"
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

// vriables for flags.
var (
    STARTDIRFLAG, DELIM string
    FLAGALL             bool
    FILES, DIRS         int
)

func checkOS() {
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        DELIM = `\`
    }else{
        DELIM = `/`
    }
}

// split full path, call building branch and
// return buit branch and name of current directory
func buildTree(path string) (*bytes.Buffer, string) {
    s := strings.Split(path, DELIM)
    b := buildBranch(s)
    return b, filepath.Base(path)
}

// exchange full path for spaces and separator
func buildBranch(s []string) *bytes.Buffer {
    b := new(bytes.Buffer)
    for i := 0; i < len(s)-1; i++ {
        b.WriteString("|  ")
    }
    return b
}

// the function shows new branch
func outputBranch(separator *bytes.Buffer, name string, color ct.Color, brightness bool) {
    separator.WriteString("|___" + name)
    ct.Foreground(color, brightness)
    fmt.Println(separator.String())
    ct.ResetColor()
}

func tree(path string) {
    fs, _ := os.ReadDir(path)
    // get spaces instead of full path
    separator, name := buildTree(path)
    if name == "." {
    } else {
        outputBranch(separator, name, ct.Blue, true)
        // increment amount of directory
        DIRS++
    }
    for _, v := range fs {
        // File may be hidden. The checking finds out if the file
        // is hidden and hide it from output if flag --all is upset
        if strings.HasPrefix(v.Name(), ".") && !FLAGALL {
            continue
        } else if v.IsDir() {
            // if current element is a directory, should
            // call this function recursively with path to the element.
            tree(filepath.Join(path, v.Name()))
        } else {
            // if current element is a regular file, should
            // get spaces with separator instead of full path
            // and single name of directory
            separator, name := buildTree(filepath.Join(path, v.Name()))
            outputBranch(separator, name, ct.White, false)
            // increment amount of flags
            FILES++
        }
    }
}

// preparing and start tree
func init() {
    checkOS()
    root := &cobra.Command{
        Use: "mytree",
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            // switch to the start directory otherwise,
            // output will be beside the middle of terminal
            err := os.Chdir(STARTDIRFLAG)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            // show start directiory on the top of tree
            ct.Foreground(ct.Blue, true)
            fmt.Println(filepath.Base(STARTDIRFLAG))
            ct.ResetColor()
            tree(".")
        },
    }
    // get default directory to show its tree if flag is upset
    home, err := os.UserHomeDir()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // get flags or set default if it's upset
    root.Flags().StringVarP(&STARTDIRFLAG, "path", "p", home, "set path to build tree")
    root.Flags().BoolVarP(&FLAGALL, "all", "a", false, "use for see hidden dirs and files")
    root.Execute()
}

func main() {
    // final message
    fmt.Println(DIRS, "directories,", FILES, "files")
}
```

Результаты моей утилиты (`mytree`) и оригинальной (`tree`):

```
my@my:~$ sudo mytree -p / | grep directories
[sudo] password for my: 
|  |  |___desktop-directories
|  |  |  |  |  |  |___import-directories.perl
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |___import-directories.perl
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |___import-directories.perl
101116 directories, 1106945 files
my@my:~$ sudo tree / | grep directories
│   │   ├── desktop-directories
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── import-directories.perl
    │   │   │   │   │   │       │   │   │   │   ├── import-directories.perl
    │   │   │   │   │   │       │   │   │   │   ├── import-directories.perl
108661 directories, 1096984 files
```